# Force lsyncd to sybc NOW

Tags: pycharm, rsync, lsyncd

I'm using lsyncd to mirror a local development directory structure with a remote server.
I'm editing files locally (with pycharm) and wait for them to be pushed unto the server when I'm done with a given change.

Is there a way to force the lsyncd daemon to perform a sync **now**, not waiting for it's delay period to end, through the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the delay time in the [lsyncd config](https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/layer4/) to a small number. I used to use lsyncd for exact this job, and I think setting it to zero worked fine then (you probably wouldn't want that for lots of files getting updated by a script, or something, but it's fine for files being hand edited).

Comment: Thanks.
Eventually I opted to use a script which runs hsync with an exclude file and run it manually every time I need a sync. I found it more productive rather than checking the server to see  if the files are already up-to-date.